# ¿Por que mi código pasa al PHP directamente?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo en mi HTML unas validaciones con JS pero el problema es que directamente salta al PHP antes de pasar por las validaciones.

**HTML**

```
<form name="formulario" action="reg.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validar();">
        <div class="inicio">
            <h1>Registro</h1>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" name="_name" id="_name">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Apellido Paterno" name="_lastName" id="_lastName">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Apellido Materno" name="_secondName" id="_secondName">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Correo" name="_email" id="_email">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" name="_password" id="_password">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Repetir Contraseña" name="_repPassword" id="_rePassword">
            <input type="file" class="btn-img" name="up-image" id="up-image">
            <div id="preview"></div>
            <button class="btn-main">Registrar Usuario</button>
            <span><a href="./index.php">Cancelar</a></span>
        </div>
</form>

<script src="reg.js"></script>
```

**JS**

```
function validar () {
  let name = document.getElementById('_name').value
  let lastName = document.getElementById('_lastName').value
  let secondName = document.getElementById('_secondName').value
  let email = document.getElementById('_email').value
  let password = document.getElementById('_password').value
  let repPassword = document.getElementById('_repPassword').value

  let expresionCorreo = /\w+@\w+\.+[a-z]/

  if (
    name === '' ||
    lastName === '' ||
    secondName === '' ||
    email === '' ||
    password === '' ||
    repPassword === ''
  ) {
    alert('Uno o varios campos estan vacios')
    return false
  } else if (!expresionCorreo.test(email)) {
    alert('El correo es invalido')
    return false
  } else if (password !== repPassword) {
    alert('Las contraseñas son diferentes')
    return false
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué te parece esta propuesta?

1º capturar el evento onclick del boton registrar usuario.
2º hacer un event.preventDefault().
3º ejecutar tu validar().
4º y por último ejecutar el tu formulario con javascrip con un .submit().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La razón por la que se envía el formulario es porque te esta dando error el `Javascript` cuando buscas obtener el `value` de `document.getElementById('_repPassword')`, el cual no existe.

Al dar error, nunca se ejecuta el `return false`, por lo que el `submit` continua su ejecución normal.

#### Solución:

El `id` del elemento es `_rePassword` (*no `_repPassword`*).

**Demo**

```js
function validar() {
  let name = document.getElementById('_name').value
  let lastName = document.getElementById('_lastName').value
  let secondName = document.getElementById('_secondName').value
  let email = document.getElementById('_email').value
  let password = document.getElementById('_password').value
  let repPassword = document.getElementById('_rePassword').value

  let expresionCorreo = /\w+@\w+\.+[a-z]/

  if (
    name === '' ||
    lastName === '' ||
    secondName === '' ||
    email === '' ||
    password === '' ||
    repPassword === ''
  ) {
    alert('Uno o varios campos estan vacios')
    return false
  } else if (!expresionCorreo.test(email)) {
    alert('El correo es invalido')
    return false
  } else if (password !== repPassword) {
    alert('Las contraseñas son diferentes')
    return false
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="formulario" action="reg.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validar();">
  <div class="inicio">
    <h1>Registro</h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" name="_name" id="_name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Apellido Paterno" name="_lastName" id="_lastName">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Apellido Materno" name="_secondName" id="_secondName">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Correo" name="_email" id="_email">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" name="_password" id="_password">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Repetir Contraseña" name="_repPassword" id="_rePassword">
    <input type="file" class="btn-img" name="up-image" id="up-image">
    <div id="preview"></div>
    <button class="btn-main">Registrar Usuario</button>
    <span><a href="./index.php">Cancelar</a></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Nuevamente gracias amigo por responder otra de mis preguntas, ya habia encontrado el error pero aun asi gracias por responderme tan rapido.